# Задание на сортировку javascript

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Задание:

Программа сортирует полученную строку определённым образом.
Строка состоит из слов и чисел, состоящих из 2-х цифр.

Пример, строка на входе:

```
four 52 along 96 25 gym root 15 hat 73 bank success 38 46
```

Сортировка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
1 шаг: along four 52 25 gym root 15 hat 73 bank success 38 46 96
2 шаг: bank along four 52 25 gym root 15 hat success 38 46 96 73
3 шаг: four bank along 25 gym root 15 hat success 38 46 96 73 52
4 шаг: gym four bank along 25 root 15 hat success 38 96 73 52 46
5 шаг: hat gym four bank along 25 root 15 success 96 73 52 46 38
6 шаг: root hat gym four bank along 15 success 96 73 52 46 38 25
7 шаг: success root hat gym four bank along 96 73 52 46 38 25 15
```

Проанализируй шаги сортировки, на основании имеющихся данных напиши алгоритм, который воспроизводит ту же самую логику сортировки.
Описать алгоритм сортировки на языке программирования javascript.

Я сделал программу только для чисел, хотел потом переделать ее и для слов, но в конечном итоге получается полный бред

```
function sortArray(arr) {
            let size = arr.length;

            for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                let minIndex = findMinIndex(arr, i, size - i - 1);
                if (minIndex !== i) {
                    // если минимальный элемент не на своем месте, перемещаем его
                    [arr[i], arr[minIndex]] = [arr[minIndex], arr[i]];
                }

                let maxIndex = findMaxIndex(arr, i, size - i - 1);
                if (maxIndex !== size - i - 1) {
                    // если максимальный элемент не на своем месте, перемещаем его
                    [arr[size - i - 1], arr[maxIndex]] = [arr[maxIndex], arr[size - i - 1]];
                }
                console.log(arr);
            }
            return arr;
        }

        function findMinIndex(arr, start, end) {
            let minIndex = start;

            for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[minIndex]) {
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }

            return minIndex;
        }

        function findMaxIndex(arr, start, end) {
            let maxIndex = end;

            for (let i = end; i >= start; i--) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[maxIndex]) {
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }

            return maxIndex;
        }

        let inputArr = [52, 96, 25, 15, 73, 38, 46];
        let sortedArr = sortArray(inputArr);
        console.log(sortedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам алгоритм предполагает, что надо наибольшее число поставить вконец строки, а наименьшее слово в начало.

Под наибольшим и наименьшем я подразумеваю код первого символа.

Воспользуемся массивом для перестановки слов в строке

```js
function letnum(c) {
  const z = c.split(' ');
  // 49 - 57 числа
  // 97-122, 65 90, буквы. Возьмем только прописные под задачу
  // Каждый обход будем находить по 1 слову и 1 числу.
  // Слово с минимальным кодом, число с максимальным кодом
  let charic = 300;
  let charIdx = 0;
  let numbers = 0;
  let numIdx = 0;
  let transform;
  for (let j = 0; j < z.length / 2; j++) {
    for (let i = j; i < z.length - j; i++) {
      // слова
      if (z[i].charCodeAt(0) > 96 && z[i].charCodeAt(0) < charic) {
        charic = z[i].charCodeAt(0);
        charIdx = i;
      }
      // числа
      if (z[i].charCodeAt(0) < 58 && z[i].charCodeAt(0) > numbers) {
        numbers = z[i].charCodeAt(0);
        numIdx = i;
      }
    }

    if (numIdx > charIdx) {
      // вырезаем элемент
      transform = z.splice(numIdx, 1)[0];
      // Добавляем его в конец массива
      z.push(transform);
      // Вырезаем элемент
      transform = z.splice(charIdx, 1)[0];
      // Добавляем его в начало массива
      z.unshift(transform);
    } else {
      transform = z.splice(charIdx, 1)[0];
      z.unshift(transform);
      // Т.к. индекс сметсился, нам надо тоже сделать сдвиг
      transform = z.splice(numIdx + 1, 1)[0];
      z.push(transform);
    }

    charic = 300;
    numbers = 0;
    console.log(j, z.join(' ')) // Промежуточные значения
  }
  // Собираем массив в строку и возвращаем результат
  return z.join(' ');
}

console.log(letnum('four 52 along 96 25 gym root 15 hat 73 bank success 38 46'))
```

Данный код будет работать для заданной строки или строки с аналогичными данными, где количество элементов(слов) будет четное, а количество слов и цифр одинаковое.

Самым универсальным решением, будет обычная сортировка массива, однако она не является решением под вашу задачу и не соблюдает заданный порядок

```js
function sortString(c) {
  // преобразуем строку в массив с разделителем "пробел"
  return c.split(' ').sort((a,b) => b.charCodeAt(0) - a.charCodeAt(0)).join(' ');
}

console.log(sortString('four 52 along 96 25 gym root 15 hat 73 bank success 38 46'))
```

Comment: Обычная сортировка будет давать нужный результат, только для этой задачи, когда числа мы получаем в строковом виде, лучше сравнивать не первые символы, а строки полностью. Вместо `b.charCodeAt(0) - a.charCodeAt(0)` пишем `b.localeCompare(a)`. А если по условию задачи в целом, то перечитав, появляется больше вопросов, чем ответов. К примеру, как вы правильно обратили внимание на чётность, почему ничего не сказано о вариативности исходной строки: возможном кол-ве слов и чисел, каком-то соотношении между ними и т.д. Зато сделан акцент на том, что числа двузначные.

Answer (score 0):

Или же над описанием задачи не заморачивались, или же вы не изложили её полностью/искажённо. Так или иначне, но когда условие оставляет много вопросов типа "а что если ...", то это не очень гуд.
Решение ниже вам может и не пригодится, но я попробовал сделать его более универсальным. Суть остаётся та же - при каждой итерации, находим первое в алфавитном порядке слово и максимально число отдельно из еще незатронутых, которые перемещаем в начало и в конец соответственно. Будет работать и со строкой, состоящей из одних слов или чисел. Соотношение слов и чисел влияет только на кол-во шагов (проходов по массиву).

```js
const sorting = str => {
  const arr = str.split(/\s+/);
  const arrLen = arr.length;

  let shiftS = 0;
  let shiftE = arrLen;

  for (let step = 0; step < arrLen; step++) {
    let minNum = null;
    let minWord = null;

    for (const v of arr.slice(shiftS, shiftE)) {
      let nan = isNaN(parseFloat(v));

      if (nan && (minWord === null || minWord >= v)) {
        minWord = v;
      }

      if (!nan && (minNum === null || +v >= +minNum)) {
        minNum = v;
      }
    }

    if (minWord === null && minNum === null) {
      break;
    }

    if (minWord !== null) {
      arr.unshift(...arr.splice(arr.indexOf(minWord, shiftS), 1));
      shiftS++;
    }
    if (minNum !== null) {
      arr.push(...arr.splice(arr.indexOf(minNum, shiftS), 1));
      shiftE--;
    }

    console.log(`${step+1} шаг: ${arr.join(' ')}`);
  }
  console.log('Finish');
};


// строка из примера
sorting('four 52 along 96 25 gym root 15 hat 73 bank success 38 46');
// разное колво слов и чисел
sorting('four 52 along 96 25 gym root hat 73 bank success');
// только слова
sorting('four along gym root hat bank success');
// только числа. * добавил еще и однозначные числа
sorting('22 2 14 87 5 35 1');
// с одинаковыми значенияим
sorting('four 52 four 52 along 96 bank four');
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, комментарии в коде.

```js
function find(lst, l, r, what, cond) { // универсальная функция поиска минимального или максимального числа или строки в указанном диапазоне поиска
    m = p = null
    for (let i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        x = lst[i]
        c = cond === '>' ? (x > m) : (x < m)
        if (typeof x === what && (c || (m === null))) { // если у значения нужный тип и условие сравнения выполняется
            m = x // запоминаем значение
            p = i // запоминаем индекс значения
        }
    }
    return p // возвращаем индекс найденного значения
}

str = 'four 52 along 96 25 gym root 15 hat 73 bank success 38 46'
lst = str.split(' ').map((x) => parseInt(x) || x); // сразу переведем числа в числа - для их быстрого различения в функции find
cnt = l = 0
r = lst.length - 1
console.log(cnt + ' шаг: ' + str)
while ((r - l) > 0) {   // повторяем, пока границы поисковой зоны в массиве не сойдутся
    i = find(lst, l, r, 'string', '<') // ищем минимальную строку в диапазоне от l до r
    lst.unshift(lst[i]) // найденное значение "вдвигаем" с левой стороны массива
    lst.splice(i + 1, 1) // удаляем исходное вхождение

    i = find(lst, l++, r--, 'number', '>')  // ищем максимальное число в диапазоне от l до r, а потом сужаем границы поисковой зоны в массиве для следующего шага
    lst.push(lst[i])    // найденное значение добавляем с правой стороны массива
    lst.splice(i, 1) // удаляем исходное вхождение

    console.log(++cnt + ' шаг: ' + lst.join(' '))   // выводим результат шага в консоль
}
```